# Zoom in and Zoom out feature in Unity 3d using UI buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I create the Zoom-in and Zoom-out feature in Unity-3d using UI button click?

Comment: By binding zoom in and zoom out methods/scripts to the buttons

Comment: Can you please suggest a sample code for this @Cid?

Comment: How would you perform a zoom in/zoom out ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on your specific setup, but this should be a good starting point, if you're using an ortographic [Camera](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html). If you're using a perspective camera instead, you should move its [Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)'s position forward or backwards. I'm also using [Mathf.Clamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) to restrict the zooming level to a specific range.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Zoomer: MonoBehaviour
{
   public Button zoomInButton;
   public Button zoomOutButton;

   public float zoomDelta = 0.1f;

   public float minZoom;
   public float maxZoom;

   Camera cam;

   void Start()
   {
      cam = Camera.main;
   }

   void OnEnable()
   {
       zoomInButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { Zoom(-zoomDelta); });
       zoomOutButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { Zoom(zoomDelta); });
   }

   void Zoom(float value)
   {
      float v = Mathf.Clamp(
         cam.orthographicSize + value,
         minZoom,
         maxZoom
      );

      cam.orthographicSize = v;
   }
}
```